# Sublevel set estimate

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\in C^2([a,b]\to\mathbb{R})$ and $|f''(x)|\geq\lambda$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and some $\lambda>0$. Let $\alpha>0$ and
\begin{equation}
E = \{ x:|f'(x)|\leq\alpha \}
\end{equation}
Show that $E$ is a closed interval and
\begin{equation}
\Big| E \Big| \leq 2 \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}.
\end{equation}

I know this is a special case for a sublevel set estimate, where $k=2$, but I don't know a simple way to prove it without using Chebyshev polynomials. I already showed $E$ is a closed interval.

Thank you.

EDIT: It's not for some constant $C$; I changed the constant to be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that E is closed because $f^{'}$ is monotone and continuous and according to a theorem in Analysis if $I$ is a closed interval so is $f^{' -1}(I)$. But I don't get the second part of the question it is obvious that there is a C with that property! It's sufficient to take C bigger than $\lambda \rvert E\lvert/ \alpha $!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like the constant $C$ to be $2$. How can I get this number? Thank you.

Comment: @dh87: $|E| = \int_E f'(x) \frac1{f'(x)} \mathrm d x$ where $E=[a,b]$ is some interval.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you. Can you please elaborate more? Am I integrating by parts?

Comment: @dh87: Oh, my bad. I meant $f''(x) \frac1{f''(x)}$. I would say substitution, as there is already the derivative of $f'$. Just remember that $f'$ has an inverse.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you so much!!!